# v-if on Vuex getter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am using a vuex getters isLoggedIn to check if a user is logged in or not.

```
<div v-if="isLoggedIn" class="ml-2 py-2 group relative">...</div>
```

```
data() {
            return {
                isLoggedIn: this.$store.getters['auth/isLoggedIn']
            }
        },
```

It doesn't work. But If I don't set the value of getters to data and check the condition directly in v-if instead of, it will work. Something like this:

```
// This works for me.
<div v-if="this.$store.getters['auth/isLoggedIn']" class="ml-2 py-2 group relative">...</div>
```

I don't know what is the difference? Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

use `computed`, `data` only execute once

```
computed:{ 
   isLoggedIn(){return this.$store.getters['auth/isLoggedIn']} 
}
```